# JS Variable is outputting as isNaN when I need a number

Tags: javascript

Here is the assignment so it's clear what I'm trying to do.

> Write a program that calculates the price of a hotel room based on three factors. First, how many will be in one room: 1-2, 3-4, or 5-6? No more than six are allowed in a room.  Second, are the guests members of AAA?  Third, do they want a room with a view? The rate is calculated as follows:
>
> Basic room rate is:
>           1-2 people = $50/night
>           3-4 people = $60/night
>           5-6 people = $70/night
>       There is a discount for AAA members off of the basic room rate per night:
>           1-2 people = 15%
>           3-4 people = 10%
>           5-6 people = 5%
>       A room with a view costs 10% more per night after all other calculations are performed.
>
> The program should prompt the user for all the inputs, perform the calculations and output the total cost per night. It is suggested to use at least some nested if/else structures to calculate the cost.

Debuggers like firebug and JSLint haven't been any help and I suspect I'm just doing something completely wrong, though I haven't had trouble with "nested if" logic assignments before. Regardless I am a complete and utter newby.

When I test by inputting 1 for numberOfGuests, N for tripleAStatus, and N for roomView, finalRate is returning as isNaN (I know this means not a number), and I can't figure out why.

```
//Variable Declaration

var numberOfPeople;
var tripleAStatus;
var roomView;
var discountRate;
var roomRate;
var finalRate;
var discountPercent;

//Input

numberOfPeople = prompt("How many guests will their be? 6 Maximum.");


tripleAStatus = prompt("Are you a AAA Member? Y/N.");

roomView = prompt("Would you like your room to have a view?");



//Logic

if ((numberOfPeople <= 2) && (numberOfPeople > 0)) {
   roomRate = 50;
   discountPercent = .15;
} else if ((numberOfPeople <= 4) && (numberOfPeople > 2)) {
   roomRate = 60;
   discountPercent = .10;
} else if ((numberOfPeople <= 5) && (numberOfPeople > 4)) {
   roomRate = 70;
   discountPercent = .5;
} else {
   alert("Your number of guests must be at least 1 and no more than 6");
}

if (tripleAStatus = "Y") {
   discountRate = roomRate - (roomRate * discountRate);
} else if (tripleAStatus = "N") {
   discountRate = roomRate;
} else {
   alert("You need to answer with either Y or N");
}

if (roomView = "Y") {
   finalRate = (discountRate) + ((discountRate) * .10);
} else if (roomView = "N") {
   finalRate = discountRate;
} else {
   alert("You need to answer with either Y or N");
}

//Output

document.write("Total cost per night is " + "$" + finalRate);
```

Comment: You're assigning to variables during your if-statements. JavaScript uses `==` and `===` for testing equality.

Comment: Your NaN ("not a number") probably comes from the fact that you use the variable `discountRate` before it's ever assigned a value in this statement: `discountRate = roomRate - (roomRate * discountRate);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like

```
discountRate = roomRate - (roomRate * discountRate);
```

Should read

```
discountRate = roomRate - (roomRate * discountPercent);
```

Which is why you're getting `NaN` in finalRate; discountRate hasn't been defined at this point, so your code actually reads `discountRate = 1 - (1 * undefined)`.

As other posters have mentioned, you also need to change your conditionals to use `==` or `===`; `=` is an assignment operator, so rather than checking if `tripleAStatus` is `"Y"`, you're actually checking if `"Y"` evaluates to `true` (which it always will).

```
tripleAStatus = 'N';
if (tripleAStatus = 'Y') {
    // tripleAStatus is now "Y", and the code inside this if will always be executed
}
```

Working changes: http://jsfiddle.net/5ZVkE/

Comment: Thank you! Total oversight on my part, the way = works in JS totally slipped my mind and wasn't coming back. I also learned a lesson in not making my variable names too similar because I was never able to catch the discountRate/discountPercent mixup.

Comment: Glad to help! I'd suggest having a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use for a discussion of why you should almost always use `===`, and how it differs from `==` :)

Answer (score 0):

In your If statements, you are assigning values by using single "=". Since the assignment always occurs, it will return true. In order to compare values, you need to use double "==" in the if statement. like this:

```
if (tripleAStatus == "Y") {
   discountRate = roomRate - (roomRate * discountRate);
} else if (tripleAStatus == "N") {
   discountRate = roomRate;
} else {
   alert("You need to answer with either Y or N");
}
```

Comment: Note that assignment doesn't return true on success as you suggest (it can't really fail), but rather returns the value that was assigned, which happens to be non-false (0, null, undefined, etc.) and therefore true.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the single '=' in your 'if' statements with '=='. You're currently using assignment operators instead of equality.

e.g.:

```
if (tripleAStatus == "Y") ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using assignments instead of equality operators in your if statements.  i.e. change

```
if (tripleAStatus = "Y")
```

to

```
if (tripleAStatus == "Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `===`!! this way, the type in the statement isn't `casted` and therefor more strictly checked if its the same type.

```
if (tripleAStatus === "Y") {
   discountRate = roomRate - roomRate * discountRate;
} else if (tripleAStatus === "N") {
   discountRate = roomRate;
}
```

/e -> & its faster!

Answer (score 0):

`prompt()` returns a STRING not a NUMBER.

Use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) with `numberOfPeople`.

And the other problem, you copied and pasted the wrong variable names in your formulas. Look at how you are using `discountRate` instead of `discountPercent`.